# Markdown, Perl and character encoding: rendering non-ASCII characters

Tags: perl, character-encoding, windows-8.1, markdown

I'm new to Markdown and I instantly liked the idea of a readable plain text document with the ability to (rather) easily convert to html. Writing on plain-text editors is way better than in word processors! The thing is, I'm not familiar with the Perl language.

So I read basically all the documentation, starting with the point of origin (daringfireball by John Gruber) and then I installed Perl in my Windows 8 operating system so I could convert my **`.md files to html`**.
 
I used the `ActivePerl-5.20.1.2000-MSWin32-x64-298557.msi version`. To make the conversion, I used the following command in the console:

```
perl Markdown.pl input.txt > output.html
```

Problem is, I'm not a native English speaker, and my texts do have a lot of **`accented characters, like á, ã, ç, ô and so on`**.
 So my output is a very ugly (and unreadable) text like:

```
Agora, um cÃƒÂ³digo com mais de um parÃƒÂ¡grafo
```

I've searched, but the closest I could find here was:
[Rendering unicode characters in Markdown from Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565421/rendering-unicode-characters-in-markdown-from-emacs)

How to make those non-ASCII characters show correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line `before the print` statements in your Perl program.

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
```

Also see: [How can I output UTF-8 from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chankey, sorry for the long time without a response. So, I tried you suggestion and appended your line before *each* Print statement. You said statementS! No luck. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you switch to a more mature Markdown implementation, like for example [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

Pandoc supports UTF-8 and UTF-8 only.

```
pandoc -s -o output.html input.txt
```

[A comparison between the two.](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-vs-Markdown.pl)

Comment: Karol, thanks for your tip and sorry for the long time for my reply. I'll take a careful look at Pandoc.